# Wi-Fi Adapter Not found / Wi-Fi is disabled

Tags: ubuntu, wifi

My Wi-Fi on Ubuntu system recently stopped working. When I hover over toolbar it says: "Wi-Fi is disabled", in Networks app it says: "Wi-Fi adapter not found". I dual-boot with Windows and on Windows it works like a charm. Wired connection also works well. Here is output of `sudo lshw -C network`:

```
  *-network DISABLED        
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Dual Band Wireless-AC 3165 Plus Bluetooth
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:07:00.0
       logical name: wlp7s0
       version: 99
       serial: 30:24:32:41:1a:36
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.15.0-45-generic firmware=29.1044073957.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:144 memory:a4300000-a4301fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: enp8s0
       version: 15
       serial: 8c:16:45:a0:2a:08
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.88.46 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:17 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:a4204000-a4204fff memory:a4200000-a4203fff
```

Comment: Is the machine a laptop?  If so, is there a hardware wifi kill switch that may have accidentally been activated?

Comment: This is laptop and there is no hardware switch.